# How can I connect to my hana xs service and consume it as oData in my ui5 project?

Tags: odata, sapui5, hana-xs

my aim is to create an [oDataModel](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html) and consume my services. I can see my all entities under this url : https://s12hanaxs.hanatrial.ondemand.com/account_name/schema_name/service_name.xsodata/ with my trial account. I followed [these steps](http://go.sap.com/developer/tutorials/hcp-create-destination.html) to create oData service but I got ***Internal Server Error*** at 13th steps when I click the run button to load service metadata. The only difference that I made is to use **Basic Authentication** when I create the destination. And here my destination configuration :

[image: destination config]

**Edit 1:** 
I wanted to show my.xsaccess file for my services :

```
{
    "exposed": true,
    "authentication": [{
        "method": "Basic"
    }],
    "authorization" : [ "account_name.schema_name::Basic" ],
    "mime_mapping": [{
        "extension": "jpg",
        "mimetype": "image/jpeg"
    }],
    "force_ssl": false,
    "enable_etags": true,
    "prevent_xsrf": true,
    "anonymous_connection": null,
    "cors": [{
        "enabled": false
    }],
    "cache_control": "no-cache, no-store",
    "default_file": "index.html"
}
```

I also can't send a http request via [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't. I created a service and through this service I was able to do transactions. But not directly consuming xs services. I was using trial version maybe that's why I am not able reach my entities via Basic Authentication. Database is only shareable with me and I don't have database's password and username. But I'm not sure about this as well.

Comment: I had a similar experience with HCP Trial. It seems that Basic Auth is not allowed there. Works perfectly fine on a payd HCP account though.

Comment: I think the destination file is used to consume external services not to explose your services

Answer (score 0):

Local sap Web Ide should work for you.

Comment: Should be a comment, instead of answer!